# Android: option menu only in a tab

Tags: android, menu, tabs, visibility

I have a screen with `4 tabs`and a `res/menu`. I want an option only appears on the first tab. If I put `visible(true)` on the tab 1 `onTabChanged` only option appears when I click on the tab not at startup.

Where should I place the visible(true) to load at the start and only shows in the tab1? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are trying to do it can be achieve with this way also.

You can create 4 separate activities for your 4 different tabs. And define them using fragments in tab host

Only in first Activity you can define the

```
 onOptionsItemSelected
```

And for other activities you just delete the items in res/menu